# Python nested dictionary to pandas df

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I am trying to convert my nested dictionary to a pandas DataFrame.
My Dictionary looks like:

```
my_dict = {'google.com' : {'111,\n222,\n333,\n444' : 'google.com/111,\ngoogle.com/222,\ngoogle.com/333,\ngoogle.com/444'},
            'bing.com'  : {'111,\n222,\nE321A,\n123x' : 'bing.com/111,\nbing.com/222,\nbing.com/E321A,\nbing.com/123x'}}
```

I need to get the output as:
[image]

I tried using:

```
    pd.DataFrame.from_dict()
```

But Didn't get the desired output.

Comment: Well, yes, that's because your nested dictionary doesn't look like something that makes sense for the task. If you want `111`, `222` etc. to produce separate rows, then they should be separate keys in the dict. You need to do something to parse the `'111,\n222,\n333,\n444'` etc. strings and structure the inner dicts in a way that makes sense (like `{'111': 'google.com/111', '222': 'google.com/222'}` etc.). It would help if you showed the code that you used to create `my_dict`.

Comment: That's fine; there's still something wrong with that overall process, and it would help if we could see that process.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel  Data has been already in string and this dictionary has been created from 3 different dictionaries. 
dict_DomainFlagged will contain {'google.com': 4,'bing.com': 4}
and dict_ID will contain `{'google.com' : '111,\n222,\n333,\n444',
 'bing.com' : '111,\n222,\nE321A,\n123x'}`
and dict_LinkList will contain `{'google.com' : 'google.com/111,\ngoogle.com/222,\ngoogle.com/333,\ngoogle.com/444',
       'bing.com' : 'bing.com/111,\nbing.com/222,\nbing.com/E321A,\nbing.com/123x'}` then:
`for dom in dict_DomainFlagged.keys():
    my_dict [dom] = {dict_ID[dom]: dict_LinkList[dom]}`

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I have separated the string into keys and values as you mentioned above. `{'111': 'google.com/111', '222': 'google.com/222'}` . Now how to make a pandas df as mention in the question.  **Thank You**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
parsed_dict = {
    k: dict(zip(list(v.keys())[0].split(",\n"), list(v.values())[0].split(",\n")))
    for k, v in my_dict.items()
}

df = pd.concat(
    {k: pd.DataFrame.from_dict(v, "index") for k, v in parsed_dict.items()}, axis=0
)
df = df.reset_index()
df.columns = names=['Domain', 'ID','Link'] 
df.set_index(['Domain', 'ID'], inplace=True)
```

```
parsed_dict 
{'google.com': {'111': 'google.com/111', '222': 'google.com/222', '333': 'google.com/333', '444': 'google.com/444'}, 'bing.com': {'111': 'bing.com/111', '222': 'bing.com/222', 'E321A': 'bing.com/E321A', '123x': 'bing.com/123x'}}
```

```
df

                            Link
Domain     ID                   
google.com 111    google.com/111
           222    google.com/222
           333    google.com/333
           444    google.com/444
bing.com   111      bing.com/111
           222      bing.com/222
           E321A  bing.com/E321A
           123x    bing.com/123x
```